# How to find messages sent by me? PubNub ChatEngine

Tags: websocket, chat, history, pubnub

Tell me how to get the message history sent from me.

each user has their own chat channel to which any user can send a message.
on the client side, messages are sorted by user.

How to get the story from my channel is clear, because all messages are needed there. but there are no messages from me, because I sent a message to another channel.

```
chat.search({
    event: 'message',
    sender: ChatEngine.me,
    limit: 20
}).on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('this is an old event!', data);
}).on('$.search.finish', () => {
    console.log('we have all our results!')
});
```

The sender parameter gives an unsuccessful search.

Comment: The code snippet you provided appears to be correct for retrieving previously sent messages from history with ChatEngine. Think of a `chat` object as a room where multiple are chatting. You can use a single chat for multiple users to `emit` messages. If a user has used `emit` in a chat, the `.search` code you provided will show that user's previously sent messages. If you are still having issues with implementation, please reach out to support@pubnub.com.